# Howto IMPORT Java objects with relationship from .csv file into MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, csv, import

let say we have 2 entities:

1. Person entity - has 2 attributes **person_id** (manual input) and **firstname**
2. Address entity - has 2 attributes **address_id** (auto-increment) and **streetname**

Each Person has one Address (OneToOne relationship). So Address entity will have a foreign key (person_id) pointing to its associated Person.
What will you suggest howto go about this?

Until now I have only found a way to import single entities into mysql without relationship management:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE person 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: I assume person has an auto incrementing key, and it needs to match with something like user_id in the address table?

Comment: Hi FrankerZ, thank you for your time. I am awefully sorry for not having expressed myself in a concise manner. The pk (id) of the Person entity will be given manually but the pk of Address (id) will be auto-incremented. Just as you have anticipated, the user_id will be the fk in the Address table. Right now I have written a Java method to read from the csv file in order to create objects and then persisting them into the database. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to go about within the functionality of mysql itself.

Comment: It's no problem. That's what comments are for =)

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution. If you're happy with the response, please mark an answer as accepted, otherwise let me know and I can assist further.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and it indeed solved my problem! This is the way to go. Thank you once again for your time and effort. Cheers =)

Comment: I tried your first solution approach in that I modified the creation of the temporary table to include a column called person_id since the person_id was given beforehand. After that I just bulk loaded from the .csv file into the temp table. Then I created tables for Person and Address objects (id is autoincremented) and followed your approach.

Comment: I have come to realize that we talked past each other in that you assumed that the person_id is generated via auto-increment. But only address_id is auto-incremented while the person_id is given. Therefore your second approach with the UUID doesn't quite fit with my requirements, yet I will try it out to learn more about the UUID since this is the first time I came across the topic of UUID (I only know that its content is somehow generated with current time properties)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120818/discussion-between-frankerz-and-chiggiddi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, unfortunately this is going to be a tough answer, but likely it's the only way without modifying your table for an insert (Which is highly not recommended).

1. Create a temporary table

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `import` (
        `person_name` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        `person_age` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        `address1` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        `city` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2. Do bulk load (As you showed in your question)
3. Do a select from your import table, and loop through each row
4. Insert into address table, get last_insert_id, and then insert into user table with the last insert id
5. Drop your temp table with: `` DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `import`; ``

If you consider dropping the auto incrementing id, and move toward a [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) instead, you can do this with 3 queries.

1. Create a temporary table

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `import` (
        `uuid` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        `person_name` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        `person_age` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        `address1` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        `city` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2. Do bulk load:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/file.csv' 
    INTO TABLE person 
    (@dummy, person_name, person_age, address1, city)
    SET uuid = UUID()
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

3. Do your inserts:

```
    INSERT INTO address (id, address1, city)
    SELECT uuid, address1, city
    FROM `import`;

    INSERT INTO person (address_id, person_name, person_age)
    SELECT uuid, person_name, person_age
    FROM `import`;
```

5. Drop your temp table with: DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `import`;

Comment: Hi FrankerZ. To be honest, I am quite new to MySQL.Yesterday my head was filled with crap; couldn't see through your recommended steps. But now I have looked at your suggestion again and now suddenly I understand it. To sum it up, beforehand I need to consolidate the data of Person and Address into a single table, from which I then need to perform for each row 2 different inserts: first for the Person, then for the Address along with the last_insert_id of its associated Person. This way everything sounds very plausible, right?
Thanks again for your help! :D

Comment: Yes. The problem with everything is simply that auto incrementing ID. Because you have one on the address, it makes it extremely difficult to insert into multiple tables, as you need to get that ID first before doing anything. Because you're unable to do the load data directly on that table, you have to use a script to loop through and pull out the data to get those insert id's (One at a time).

Comment: Wow, you are a very fast. I am just wondering how fast you reply with this swift typing and attachment of solution code. Jesus, I guess you must be a professional working in this field for quite some time. Moreover the American working attitude did the rest to shape you in your working habit. You have all my respect!